# Why is it called the "quenched" approximation in QCD?

Tags: terminology, history, strong-force

The quenched approximation of QCD (or other QCD-like theories) is when you basically ignore fermion loops, i.e. fermions are non-dynamical fields. For quantities that do not involve external fermion states, this is equivalent to setting $N_f=0$ (since fermion lines have to be connected/continuous).

But why is this approximation called the "quenched" approximation? Here are the dictionary definitions of "quenched".

1. satisfy (one's thirst) by drinking; satisfy (a desire).
2. extinguish (a fire)
3. stifle or suppress (a feeling).
4. rapidly cool (red-hot metal or other material), especially in cold water or oil.

When I look at the phrase-usage history since 1970 on Google Ngram Viewer, I get the following result (which I don't know if it's really a good representation of reality):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Quenching" in physics (in this kind of context) means "doing something very fast, much faster than any other dynamical process in the system. So that what you are doing ends up being the dominant effect".

In this sense, the best definition is #4. 
 See for instance this definition of metal quenching:

> Quenching is a rapid way of bringing metal back to room temperature
>   after heat treatment to prevent the cooling process from dramatically
>   changing the metal's microstructure.

That is, you want to cool the metal *faster* than its microstructure can re-arrange itself. I.e. you want the cooling to be the *only* dynamics that the metal responds to: to ensure that, this needs to happen much faster than any other process.

I am no expert in this, but from I can read online the quenched approximation in QCD means no light quarks are allowed to propagate. 
 Hence you are assuming that whatever process you are simulating happens on a faster scale than said light fermions' lifetimes and/or dynamical process duration.